# Spark TBLPROPERTIES to sql query?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

there is pyspark a construct like `SHOW TBLPROPERTIES table_path` or `SET TBLPROPERTIES(key='value')`

How this can be converted to normal sql or sql-like query or final target query, that has to be performed to target table - viewed?

Comment: please give more details.

Comment: There is a trino-db connection. I can set the metadata properties via Spark `SET TBLPROPERTIES` (it's not the default metadata fiedls, it works on absolutely custom string names and values). But raw sql query cannot do the same (like syntax not supported), I would like to translate this spark syntax onto regular query. Also I would like to be able to translate `spark.sql(...)` for another cases and read what exact query will be performed to target table.